# Identify time point in DataFrame based on condition per time series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with time series data, as such below:

(TP = time point)

```
gene number   TP1   TP2   TP3   TP4   TP5   TP6
gene1         0.4   0.2   0.1   0.5   0.8   1.9
gene2         0.3   0.05  0.5   0.8   1.0   1.7
....
```

For each row (gene), I want to identify the TP at which its value reaches a level 4 times larger than the minimum value in the time series, with the additional condition that this identified TP has to be AFTER the minimum TP. So, in case of gene 2, I am interested in TP3 and not TP1 (which is 4 times larger than the minimum value of TP2) because TP1 is earlier in the series than minimum TP2.

So the outcome of the script that I am trying to build is this:

```
gene1    TP4
gene2    TP3
...
```

I have my data in a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first create a mask `ma` and set all the row values before the minimum to `False`. Next, use this mask find the values in each row *after* the minimum to hit 4 times the minimum (indicated by `True`):

```
>>> ma = df.values.argmin(axis=1)[:,None] <= np.arange(df.shape[1])
>>> df.ge(4*df.min(axis=1), axis=0) & ma
         TP1    TP2    TP3   TP4   TP5   TP6
gene1  False  False  False  True  True  True
gene2  False  False   True  True  True  True
```

You can then retrieve the labels of the first `True` values from this boolean DataFrame (which I'll call `df1`) with `idxmax`:

```
>>> df1.idxmax(axis=1)
gene1    TP4
gene2    TP3
dtype: object
```

Comment: How would I apply it on a specific slice of the data frame, e.g. I want to run the script for each row, but only using columns 6 through 12?

Comment: You can get a slice of your DataFrame with `df.iloc[:, 6:12]` (`iloc` selects by index number, endpoints are included).

Comment: Alternatively, you can choose the columns by label, e.g. `df[['TP6', 'TP7', ...]]`

Comment: it seems that when a row does not hit a 4-times value, the script returns the first column. That's not a big problem by itself, but just checking that I get it right. Second, how would I change the parameter to instead of "4 times the minimum", a "value above zero"?

Comment: That seems correct, yes - when the 4-times value is not reached, the whole row is False (that is, zero) so all values are the maximum and the first column is returned. I'd overlooked that point but, as you say, it should be reasonably straightforward to work around.

Comment: Yes, that's not a big problem, but I understand now.. Also, I thought I got the "zero" figured out: `df.ge(0, axis=0) & ma` but it doesn't work as I expected. The issue is that I have values below zero, and I want to change the parameter to the "first TP, after the minimum, where the value goes above zero"..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70879/discussion-between-oaklander114-and-ajcr).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'TP1':[.4,.3],'TP2':[.2,.05],'TP3':[.1,.5],'TP4':[.5,.8],'TP5':[.8,1.0], 'TP6':[1.9,1.7]},index= ['gene1','gene2'])

def f(x):
    #get min value and index
    min_ind = [ e for e in enumerate(x) if e[1] == x.min()]
    #return only the first value that is greater than the index of the min value and > min value *4
    r =df.columns[[e[0] for e in enumerate(x) if e[1] if e[1] > min_ind[0][1]*4 and e[0]> min_ind[0][0]][0]]
    return r
```

returns:

```
df.apply(f, axis=1)

gene1    TP4
gene2    TP3
dtype: object
```

Comment: That works on the example, but when running it on my data, which is of larger format (92rowsx42columns), I get this error:

`IndexError: ('index out of bounds', u'occurred at index 305107')`

305107 is the first index in the table